# How do I boot Ubuntu from the Windows 10 Bootloader?

Tags: lts

I don't like GRUB (especially the look.) I don't want to use BURG if I don't have to and was wondering if I could boot into Ubuntu (and RemixOS) from the Windows 10 bootloader.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually not really.

You can boot directly into BCD (Windows Boot Manager) and if you can manage to add a boot item for Ubuntu (*which is a real pain*), you cannot avoid to boot into GRUB (*or whatever Ubuntu uses*).

The only way to avoid the Linux boot loader to appear, is to set the automatic boot option and the timeout to 0. 
 But really, I can **not** recommend that, because if you have a problem with Ubuntu you are not able to boot into a previous update version or a repair mode!

Whatever your first boot manager is, with a dual boot system (Windows and Linux) you will always need to go through two boot managers – unless your dual boot system is both Linux/Unix or Windows/M$ family.

Comment: I boot directly to Win7 with BCD /dev/sda (grub is NOT installed)   and boot to Ubuntu on /dev/sdb which of course grub is invoked. I bypass grub completely for Win 7 by invoking a boot selector in bios to choose SSD

Comment: Well, if I understand correctly you enter BIOS each time to change the boot disk?
That's not necessary. You can add a boot entry into BCD for the Linux boot partition on sdb. But this is quite difficult and therefore you will need to study how to edit BCD. I couldn't manage that myself (same HDD situation here), so I'm using GRUB to boot into WIndows (BCD) which is far more easy.

Comment: Howsoever, you cannot avoid booting Linux and Windows without invoking its boot manager.

Comment: I don't enter bios configuration ... when I want to use Windows I use the boot selector and choose the windows drive for one session only.  I use the native boot manager for each OS. I've had problems with Windows Update when booting Windows from grub. I am able to boot Windows from grub I simply choose NOT TO.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't know this boot selector thing (still using legacy BIOS). This Windows issue with updating is imminent. You must boot with BCD (and from the invoked boot sector) or you won't be able to update Windows. The only way to get Linux boot from this HDD is to use a BCD editor. I'm sorry to say, but I still hadn't the time (and space) to work with Win10, so I can't say what new "impossibilities" M$ has build in that new BCD. But – just now – I got an idea I'll have to test. So let me check it – could take a day or two … or less …